# How choose random element in swift?

Tags: swift

I am absolutely new in swift and try to find a way for changing the color of labels randomly

```
for i in 1...20 {
 let label = [label1, label2, label3]
 let a = label.randomElement()
 a.textColor = UIColor.orange // there is the problem
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, never mind, it looks like you're already doing it correctly. What exactly is wrong here?

Comment: Hey, the error is "Value of type 'UILabel??' has no member 'textColor'"

Answer (score 2):

Collection method `randomElement()` returns an optional. If your collection element is already optional you have a double optional. You need to use optional chaining or unwrap your optional.

```
a?.textColor = .orange  // if your `a` label is of type `UILabel?` use a single exclamation mark
```

Comment: thank you! I read your answer late. I did it like that: 

let label:[UILabel] = [label1, label2, label3]
let a = arc4random_uniform(3)
label[Int(a)].textColor = UIColor.green

Comment: @Shervin better to stick with the randomElement. You can use `if let`
 to unwrap the optional.